# Ansible - How to Escape Nested Jinja within Filter

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

I want to use nested jinja expression within filter, but am failing it to do.

I have a variable file that looks like this:

```
NAME: "test"
VAR: ["a","b","c-test","d", "t-test"]
```

and now, I want to use ansible filters in the same variable file to extract a specific string from the VAR list.

I have tried:

```
NAME: "test"
VAR: ["a","b","c-test","d","test-t"]

testc: "{{ VAR | select('match', 'c-{{ NAME }}') | list }}"
testt: "{{ VAR | select('match', '{{ NAME }}-t') | list }}"
```

and

```
NAME: "test"
VAR: ["a","b","c-test","d","test-t"]

testc: "{{ VAR | select('match', 'c-\'{{ NAME }}\'') | list }}" 
testt: "{{ VAR | select('match', '{{ NAME }}-t') | list }}"
```

with no success.

I have the same issue to use nested Jinja within filters other the 'select'.

How do you use or escape the nested jinja expression within ansible filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest double curly brackets. Names inside double curly brackets are evaluated as variables already so you don't need to enclose them in another pair of double curly brackets to evaluate them. You can simply use the concatenation operator `~` to concatenate the string literal `'c-'` with the variable `NAME` directly:

```
test: "{{ VAR | select('match', 'c-' ~ NAME) | list }}"
test: "{{ VAR | select('match', NAME ~ '-t') | list }}"
```

Comment: If the VAR also has "test-t", that how do you escape "~"?
I tried backslash, but didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `VAR` also having `"test-t"`, and why you want to escape `"~"`. Can you post your code of the attempt?

Comment: I editted the question again to show you what "VAR" I am referring to. I was wondering how to use ~ when the variable comes first before the string.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Learned new things.